# PHP CodeSniffer: LF ou CRLF?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Olá

Eu já vi uma pergunta aqui sobre o problema do fim de linha que o PHP CodeSniffer exibe:

`End of line character is invalid; expected "\n" but found "\r\n"`

Porém, a minha dúvida é um pouco diferente...

Eu utilizo Windows, e o VS Code deixa como padrão o **CRLF** em todos os arquivos que eu crio, e eu sei que para resolver esse problema que o PHP CodeSniffer informa, basta trocar para **LF**. E a grande questão é: O fato de eu estar mudando para LF prejudica os meus códigos em algum aspecto? levando a consideração que eu utilizo o Windows e não Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não prejudica nada em Linux porque o interpretador PHP sabe o que precisa, no entanto devo ressaltar que pode dependendo de como configurou o GIT, irá sincronizar conforme o sistema operacional, mesmo que você manualmente troque todos CRLF por LF, então para facilitar e evitar ficar vendo tais mensagens você poderia padronizar usando o arquivo `.editorconfig` para que todos editores (modernos) usem o mesmo padrão

- Instale no Vscode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig
- No SublimeText no packagecontrol busque por `EditorConfig`
- Outros editores: https://editorconfig.org/#download

Dentro do documento `.editorconfig` deve ficar algo como:

```
root = true

[*.{js,css,php,html}]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

E para o git crie um arquivo chamado `.gitattributes` e coloque algo como:

```
* text=auto
* text eol=lf
```

Neste caso os textos irão usar como LF, porque PHP executa como LF em Windows e em Linux sem problema, como eu disse o interpretador entende, no `.editorconfig` eu coloquei um ajuste para os arquivos `.md` porque o markdown as vezes precisa de espaços até a quebra de linha em alguns casos, configure essa parte como desejar:

```
charset = utf-8             # charset padrão que irá usar em seus arquivos
end_of_line = lf            # quebra de linha padrão
insert_final_newline = true # adicionar ou não linha vazia no final do documento
indent_style = space        # trocar tabs por espaços
indent_size = 4             # indentação com TAB se torna em 4 espaços (depende de indent_style)
```